# Old IP keeps coming back

Tags: pi-hole

I got a new router, and my raspberry pi keeps adding the old IP to my system everyday. I have tried assigning a static ip, flushing the interface, making sure that the old ip is in none of the files, but everyday it adds the old route back. I use my pi as a pihole, so my wifi goes down everyday until I remove the old route. Can anyone help me out?

Comment: `keeps adding the old IP to my system` - what do you mean exactly?

Comment: Please edit your question and post the contents of /etc/network/interfaces and /etc/dhcpcd.conf (without the comment lines).

Comment: @abolotnov   Everyday, it adds the old IP address (192.168.1.x) to the route table as the default even though I have the new IP (192.168.50.x) set as the default. This causes it to try to use the old IP, crashing my network because I use my pi as a pihole.

Answer (score -1):

Your question is not clear, however, you can add `ifconfig eth0 192.168.1.X netmask 255.255.255.0 up` to the rc.local. This file is located to `/etc`, So, do the following:

1.`sudo nano /etc/rc.local`.
 2. Add `ifconfig eth0 192.168.1.X netmask 255.255.255.0 up` to `/etc/rc.local`. Note that add this command between `fi` and `exit 0` and `X` is the IP's host id.
 3. `sudo reboot`.

You can also add `ifconfig eth0 192.168.56.X netmask 255.255.255.0 down` to disable the unusable IP.

The  *rc.local*  script runs on each startup.

Comment: So I should add the working IP to rc.local?

Comment: Yes, And also disable the unusable IP.

Comment: That broke it completely. It broke the dhcpcd service and I had to reset that.

Comment: Please take note that using `/etc/rc.local` has limitations due to [Compatibility with SysV](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/Incompatibilities/). We have seen many problems here on this site using it. Following the recommendation of the developers from **systemd** you should avoid using it.